Manually run Flyway migration using gradle flyway plugin in Micronaut
I am trying to run flyway migration manually instead of running when the application start, using the following reference - https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/gradle-task-184127407.html
In the build.gradle I have added the below dependency
plugins {
    id("org.flywaydb.flyway") version "11.0.1"
}

Application.properties
datasources.default.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/school_staff
datasources.default.username=keycloak
datasources.default.password=password
datasources.default.dialect=POSTGRES
datasources.default.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
datasources.default.schema-generate=NONE


flyway.datasources.default.enabled=false

Under resources -> db -> migration I have the below migration as V1__Initial__Migration
CREATE TABLE tag
(
    id   UUID NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    CONSTRAINT pk_tag PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

From the documentation of the Gradle plugin I have to add below configuration
flyway {
    url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/school_staff"
    user = "keycloak"
    password = "password"
    locations = arrayOf("classpath:db/migration")
    baselineOnMigrate = true
}

// Ensure classes are built before migration
tasks.named("flywayMigrate").configure {
    dependsOn(tasks.named("classes"))
}

When I run the ./gradlew flywayMigration
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flywayMigrate'.
> Error occurred while executing flywayMigrate
  No database found to handle jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/school_staff

How to use the datasource from the application.properties the datasources.default.url

The only thing that worked as putting the build script the top of the file
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.flywaydb:flyway-database-postgresql:11.1.0")
    }
}

